# Conditions for: (local) lipschitz stability of I-projection

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, entropy, information-geometry

The following post builds on [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/442315/edit); I'll begin by quoting the setting.

---

**Background from Previous Question:**

$\newcommand\SS{P}\newcommand\TT{Q}$Call a Gaussian probability measure $\SS$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ *isotropic* if its covariance matrix is diagonal with non-vanishing determinant; i.e. $\Sigma_{i,i}>0$ for $i=1,\dots,d$ and $\Sigma_{i,j}=0$ whenever $i\neq j$ for each $i,j=1,\dots,d$.
*Note: My definition of "isotropic" includes "the usual isotropic Gaussian measures," which, from my limited understanding, are assumed to have a covariance of the form $\sigma I_d$ for some $\sigma>0$.*

Let $\mathcal{P}$ the set of *isotropic* Gaussian probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and let $\mathcal{Q}$ be the set of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with Lebesgue density equipped with TV distance.

Consider the *information projection (of I-projection)* defined by
\begin{align}
\pi:Q &\rightarrow \mathcal{P} 
\\
\pi(\TT) &:= \operatorname*{argmin}_{\SS\in \mathcal{P}}\, D(\SS\parallel\TT)
\end{align}

---

**Definitions:**

Let $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\mu$ denote the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, and $\nu$ the standard Gaussian probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Let $\mathcal{W}_2$ denote the $2$-Wasserstein distance.

Fix a parameter $R>0$ and let $\mathcal{Q}_R$ denote the set of Borel probability measures $\mathbb{Q}$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ which:

- $\mathbb{Q}\ll \mu$,
- $ \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mu} \in L^2(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d),\mu)$,
- $\mathcal{W}_2(\mathbb{Q},\nu)\le R$.

Is the map $\mathbb{Q}\mapsto \pi(\mathbb{Q})$ is locally-Lipschitz when considered on $\mathcal{Q}_R$?

Comment: @ABIM Thank you and thanks for updating Lipschitz to locally-Lipschtiz, Iosif's counter-example indeed shed some doubts on the global Lipschitzness of the I-projection, on its domain.

Comment: Questions like "Are there conditions under which" are hardly possible to answer satisfactorily. For instance, the tautological answer is always possible to such questions. Also, one could give any number of more or less specific examples when the conditions hold. I guess these are not the kinds of answers you want. Good questions are specific, and I think the best questions are of the yes-or-no kind. The closer you can make your question to such a one, the better is the chance to get a good answer. But asking such a qood question requires serious preparation.

Comment: @IosifPinelis This is completely fair.  I'm sorry about that.  I have given the question a lot of though, and I have made the edits to clarify the precise situation I have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is still no -- for any, however small $R>0$.

Indeed, let $d=1$. Let $g$ be the pdf of $\nu$; that is, $g$ is the standard normal pdf. Let $Q_h$ be the probability measure with pdf $(1-p)g+pq_h$, where $q_h$ is as in [the previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442343/36721) and $p\in(0,1)$ is a fixed number which is close enough to $0$ so that your condition involving $R$ hold. Then the arguments provided in the previous answer will hold here just as well:

Since $a$ is rather small, $Q_h$ is somewhat close to the mixture of (i) $\nu$ and (ii) the mixture of the rather narrow normal distributions $N(1,a^2)$ and $N(-1,a^2)$ with slightly unequal weights, $c_h\,(1+h)$ and $c_h\,(1-h)$ respectively. So, a minimizer $P_h$ of the Kullback–Leibler divergence $D(P\parallel Q_h)$ in $P$ should be sufficiently close to $(1-p)\nu+pN(1,a^2)$ or $(1-p)\nu+pN(-1,a^2)$ depending on whether the small perturbation $h$ is $>0$ or $<0$, respectively. Thus, an infinitesimally small change from, say, $h>0$ to $-h<0$ will result in quite a nonnegligible change from $P_h\approx (1-p)\nu+pN(1,a^2)$ to $P_{-h}\approx (1-p)\nu+pN(-1,a^2)$. (If $h=0$, then there will be two minimizers.)